# Symbols found in multiple objects when using static LIB and DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker, static-libraries

I wonder what is the correct way to handle the following situation:

- TheLibrary.LIB file that contains class A, B
- First.DLL uses class A, so it links with TheLibrary.lib
- Second.DLL uses code in First.DLL & class A & class B, so it links with First.DLL AND TheLibrary.lib

The result (as expected) is that class A has multiple definitions (TheLibrary.lib and First.lib)

**The question is, what is the correct way to handle this situation???**

I can think of a few options that I am not happy with neither of them:

1. Force Second.DLL to link by using the first symbol it finds (/FORCE:MULTIPLE)
2. Make First.dll to use class B, so it will be inside First.lib. This way Second.lib will not need to link with TheLibrary.lib
3. Turn TheLibrary.lib into a DLL, but let's assume this is something I really want to avoid

Comment: Your situation isn't completely clear. Specifically, are classes A and/or B *exported* from First.dll?   If so, why? what do you mean by 'Make First.dll to use class B, so it will be inside First.lib'?  In what way is class B 'inside' First.lib?  Perhaps you can post minimal repro, with complete headers and the real linker (?) error?

Comment: "TheLibrary.LIB file that contains class A, B" - so, classes A and B are being compiled by TheLibrary.LIB. They are *not* exported from First.dll.

Comment: "what do you mean by 'Make First.dll to use class B, so it will be inside First.lib'?" - It is a possible solution, but not something I like. It means that if First.dll will use class B than Second.dll will not need to link to TheLibrary.LIB and problem is solved. But this solution is bad because First.DLL does not need class B. It is a "patch", and a bad one...

Comment: "complete headers and the real linker (?) error?" - I don't have any header to share. Its a theoretical question for real-life situations if you choose to use static libs.

The linker error would be "that you have multiple implementations to a symbol" because First.LIB would have class A and TheLibrary.lib has class A.